# How to create this interface in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have this interface in typescript that looks like this:

```
interface Test {
  'some-key' : boolean
}
```

Anyone know how to convert this to kotlin? When I tried to use this in kotlin, like this:

```
interface Test {
  val 'some-key' : boolean
}
```

it is saying: "Expecting property name or receiver type"

Answer (score 3):

some-key is not a valid Kotlin identifier. You'll need to use `some_key` or (more idiomatically) `someKey` to define a property in your interface.

```
interface Test {
  val someKey: Boolean
}
```

Then implementors will be expected to define the `val someKey` property as a Boolean.

Do note that Kotlin is not like Typescript. Kotlin is nominally typed. So the interface `Test` does *not* magically encapsulate all classes ever written with a Boolean called `someKey`. Instead, it specifically acts as a supertype to classes that opt in to implementing the `Test` interface.

If what you're looking for is a type that "just contains" a Boolean, not an abstract interface that encapsulates the idea of containing a Boolean, then you want a `data class`.

```
data class Test(val someKey: Boolean)
```

This is a type that is not abstract and can be instantiated. It contains one `Boolean` concretely, which can be accessed freely by callers.

If you really do want to use something like `some-key` as a key name in Kotlin, you can surround it in backticks. Note that users of your library will have to do the same.

```
data class Test(val `some-key`: Boolean)
```

Comment: `some-key` *is* a valid identifier, just not one that follows the style guide :D  - you just have to surround it with backticks.

Comment: @Sweeper Hey, I didn't know Kotlin did that. Thanks for the tip!